# Rendering object gets cut off?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a waterfall-esque thing. As you can see in the render:

[image]

The waterfall and its particles get cut off about 4/6 ways through. (I should note that I am using the Viewport render mode, not actually rendering just yet.)
However, the exact same shot in wireframe and solid shows that everything is fine:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try do a low sample render just to double check? The Viewport preview render is a good indication but not foolproof.

Comment: Are you sure you didnt hide a glass cup in the viewer ?.
Cause i see also one particle flipping over it.
And visually its verry close to such a scene. press Alt + H on your scene (unhides hidden things)

Comment: My suspicion is that you have something set up wrong with your render layers, where the ground plane is always set to appear in front of everything.  You may wish to check in there.

Comment: BTW (completely off topic), you should probably use smooth shading on the fluid sim to improve the apparent resolution.

Comment: @Patdog Your comment solved my problem. If you could please repost it in answer form so I can credit you and you receive the reputation

Comment: Glad it helped Josh!

Answer (score 1):

Try do a low sample render just to double check? The Viewport preview render is a good indication but not foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors that could cause this but firstly click control B and make a small border in the viewpoint render and render it in the renderer this way only a small portion of the scene will be rendered to make the rendering faster, to turn off the border go to the render settings and un check border , if it is still shows halfway in the final render then check if there is any plane you hid that is covering the waterfall and the particles apart from the initial plane which the waterfall collides with. If there is none open a new blender file and in the top left portion of blender and click on file then append, search for the blender file that has the problem, click on it next click on scene and import the scene where the waterfall is, if the problem still persists.
Then check your render layers very well